Custom React Native npm package dependencies not installing automatically
I’ve created a custom React Native npm package with native code and dependencies like react-native-app-auth, @react-native-async-storage/async-storage, and @react-native-community/netinfo, listed under dependencies in custom npm package.json.
Below is my Custom package dependencies :
 "name": "custom-package",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "react": ">=18.2.0",
    "react-native": ">=0.74.5",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^8.0.1"
  },

Below is my New created project dependencies:
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "custom-package": "^0.0.1",
    "react": ">=18.2.0",
    "react-native": ">=0.74.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

I am getting this error, which is shown in this image  [enter image description here]enter image description here
When I install my custom package in a my new project, custom package dependencies aren’t installed automatically. I have to manually add them to the my new project's package.json and run pod install to make it work.
How can I ensure that the required dependencies of my custom package are automatically installed in the consuming project when the package is installed?
